# Injecting JavaScript via AJAX warning message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX that is going to a div#container as shown below

```
var loc={};
loc.script = document.createElement('script');
loc.script.type = 'text/javascript';
loc.script.src = "highcharts.js";
$("#container").prepend(loc.script);
```

But I keep getting this warning on the console:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

The code still works and functions as expected, but should I worry about this ? What's the best way to re-write my code above to remove the warning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<script>` tags loads the contents synchronously. When you create a `<script>` element with external reference, the main thread waits until it returns.

The best way to handle this is to manually load your script and inject it in to JS namespace. Jquery `getScript` function does the same. It gets the script via ajax, evaluate the script and adds it to the namespace. It really doesn't matter where the script go in the DOM tree since it is not a visual element.

```
$.getScript( "highcharts.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

[Here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) is the documentation.